# Partition table to make bootable USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, uefi, gpt

I use `fdisk` to set the partition table and to create partitions and `unetbootin` to install the OS on a USB drive.

Can anyone explain why the only partition table which makes USB boot option that appears in UEFI is the DOS one? I can use it, however, from what can be found on internet the right procedure should using a GPT table with a FAT32 filesystem.

Other information:
I tried it with `parted` to set the boot flag to "on" on the partition and it changes the type to EFI.
I also tried to set the boot flag to "on" in the GPT protective/hybrid MBR, but it says that the boot flag is already present.

Comment: I'm not sure if `fdisk` supports GPT partition tables. It's a very old and probably deprecated legacy program.

Comment: Do you suggest to try the same procedure with another software? However these are the options: Create a new label
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table,
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table,
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table,
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using the Windows or Linux `fdisk`. But if it has the GPT option, it should work.

Comment: The pc has a dual boot linux-windows